# HTTP Handler not being invoked

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, httphandler, ihttphandler

I have a custom HTTP Handler that properly implements IHttpHandler.  Below is what I've configured in my webConfig.  If I understand correctly this block *should* capture any requests with .test as the extension.

```
<handlers> 
    <add name="SampleHandler" verb="*" path="*.test" 
     type="TestApp.App_Start.CustomHandler, TestApp" />
</handlers>
```

However, the only time this handler is ever invoked is when I have a path depth of three applied to the request URL.  All other requests will 404.

For instance the handler works correctly when the path is:

```
localhost:XXX\some\fake\path\file.test
```

But not for:

```
localhost:XXX\some\file.test
```

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5, and suspect it has something to do with the routing. I also am using the sample project provided in VS2013 so besides a handler being added to the project I really haven't done anything else.

**Update:**

I've determined the default route is interfering.

```
  routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
```

Is there way to get it working even with this route configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the routing was interfering with the handler.  In order to allow the handler to recieve the request I needed to call IgnoreRoute method against the current RouteCollection ignoring any routes with .test in them:

Inside the RouteConfig class

```
  public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.test/");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

It works now.  Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the reason for you HTTP Handler not being called is because you are registering in web apps for IIS 6. For IIS 7 and above, do it like this:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="*" path="SampleHandler" 
        type="TestApp.App_Start.CustomHandler, TestApp" />
    </httpHandlers>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Comment: I dont think thats it. This tutorial shows it working http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

Comment: Check this MSDN update documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/46c5ddfy(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: Yes, it says II6. I am running II8. To add, I also tried this and IIS complained there were invalid settings.

Comment: Here is another link which may help you: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/46c5ddfy.aspx