# Custom httpHandler is unreachable

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, httphandler

I am creating a custom HttpHandler for downloading files with ".apk" extension, but when I run the code,  it never gets through my Handler. Here is my code: 
**Custom Handler** (the code in its body is only for testing - not yet fully implemented)

```
public class PackageHttpHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        context.Response.Write("<strong>CustomHandler</strong>");

        context.Response.Flush();
    }
}
```

In global **Web.config** registering handler like this in **handlers tag** of **system.webServer:**

```
add verb="*" path="*.apk" name="PackageHandler" type="MyApp.HttpHandlers.PackageHttpHandler"
```

And if I place a breakpoint in the first line of **ProcessRequest()** the code never reaches it.
What i am missing?
When i try a url: /Home/Index/Something.apk  nothing happens it loads only my default page (instead of HttpHandler code)

Also i have mimeType of .apk in Web.config

Comment: Have you traced the request itself? Maybe there is some problem with relative/absolute URLs. You could also check if there is already an existing mapping for android app packages in IIS. What you could also try is to add a ignore route for those extensions in your routing configuration file.

Comment: No not traced it, I am new in asp.net mvc and C#, so can you give me a tool for tracing it. What i learned about the Handlers are that they should be executed before Routing..

Comment: At first I would check if this would help you (IgnoreRoute): http://stackoverflow.com/a/24877108/304871

Comment: Why are there escape chars (`\*`)? Is that normal?

Comment: In my code there is no escape character, i placed it because here i can't visualize * in "", but someone Edited the post, so sorry for that. If I write to ignore **{resource}/.apk** then it works with localhost//Something.apk, but I need URLs like this:
**localhost//AppName/branch/AppName.apk**
also: **localhost//AppName/branch/version/AppName.apk**

Comment: Correct now? Post your MVC routes. Determine which exact route is causing this by commenting them one by one.

Comment: @usr I have added this ignore routes:
**routes.IgnoreRoute("{project}/{environment}/{resource}.apk/");
routes.IgnoreRoute("{project}/{environment}/{version}/{resource}.apk/");** and it now works.

Comment: Now how i can get these values {project} {version} etc.. in my Custom Handler any Idea?